# How to extract a number from a string in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a string like given below :

4 Days :10000

I want to extract the value 10000 from this string and display it in jquery. Can anyone say how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split()` or `.replace()` using regex in javascript

```js
var str = "4 Days :10000";
str = str.split(':')[1];

var str1 = str.replace(/:/, "");
console.log(str1);

$('#sample').text(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample"></div>
```